# Parent Child Record Relations to a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a database table:

```
ID    Creator    Title     GUID    Description     Rev
1     Lee         ABC      123     something        1
2     Mark        XYZ      345     something        1
3     Jone        LMN      732     something        1
4     Lee         ABC      123     new              2
```

This table shows different revisions of documents so that if a user were to update the description it would create a new Revision of that document this way we have access to the original document and the updated one.

Now my question is how would I create a list of all the documents. But if they clicked on the ABC record they would see the child of ABC which has a different revision number sort of like they are cascading (which would be done through DOM) , I'm trying to think of how a for loop would work to get this result.

I know that I would have something like this in my controller:

```
return View(db.Documents.Where(m => m.Creator == User.Identity.Name).OrderBy(m => m.GUID).ThenBy(m => m.Rev).ToList());
```

I'm trying to figure out how the View would look to show the table.

Comment: A nested loop, perhaps?  What have you tried and how did it not work as expected?  Are you just asking how to loop through a collection?

Comment: Are you asking for a LINQ query to get a list of document names and the max revision number or the design of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/. Then it would be a case of creating a loop for the table based on the data

```
@foreach(var row in Rows)
{
  //if Parent
  <tr data-tt-id="1">
     <td>Parent</td>
  </tr>
  //if Child
  <tr data-tt-id="2" data-tt-parent-id="1">
   <td>Child</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thank you so much!!!!!